# How to execute a function before and after each class method call?

Tags: javascript, hook, class-properties

I want to insert on pre execute and post execute hooks on functions in javascript classes.

Lets say I have a class like this.

```js
class Foo {
  method1(p1, p2) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
  }

  method2(p3) {
    this.p3 = p3;
  }
}
```

I want to define a before and after hook for these preexisting class methods. Something like this.

```js
class Foo {
  before(funName, ...params){
    // Should print ('method1', [p1, p2]) when method 1 is called
    // and ('method2', [p3]) when method 2 is called
    console.log(funName, params)
  }
  after(funName, result){
    // Should print the function name followed by its result
    console.log(funName, result)
  }
  method1(p1, p2) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
  }
  method2(p3) {
    this.p3 = p3;
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

What is the best way of implementing these hooks with minimal changes in existing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rough solution to the problem:

```
// we iterate over all method names
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Foo.prototype).forEach((name) => {

  // First to do: we save the original method. Adding it to prototype
  // is a good idea, we keep 'method1' as '_method1' and so on
  Foo.prototype['_' + name] = Foo.prototype[name];

  // Next, we replace the original method with one that does the logging
  // before and after method execution. 
  Foo.prototype[name] = function() {

    // all arguments that the method receives are in the 'arguments' object
    console.log(`Method call: method1(${Object.values(arguments).join(', ')})`);

    // now we call the original method, _method1, on this with all arguments we received
    // this is probably the most confusing line of code here ;)
    // (I never user this['method'] before - but it works)
    const result = this['_' + name](...arguments);

    // here is the post-execution logging
    console.log(`Method result: ${result}`);

    // and we need to return the original result of the method
    return result;
  };
});
```

Please note that this code is not part of the class itself, execute it as a normal script.

And there is a good chance that this short proof of concept crashes on real-world classes and requires some additional checks and special-case handlers, especially to get proper logging output. But it works with you Foo class.

Here's the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-fog-c803c

Comment: And Proxies would seem to be relevant? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: I tried to find a solution with proxies, as it was my first idea. But I couldn't find a way to proxy a class method that uses `this`. `this` was always undefined and I didn't figure out how to 'auto-bind' the method proxy to the class instance. If someone has a solution for that, I'd be happy to see that too.

Answer (score 0):

## Proxy solution

```js
class Foo {
  classAlias = false;

  proxyHandle = {
    // little hack where we save refrenece to our class inside the object
    main : this,
    /**
     * The apply will be fired each time the function is called
     * @param  target Called function
     * @param  scope  Scope from where function was called
     * @param  args   Arguments passed to function
     * @return        Results of the function
     */
    apply : function (target, scope, args) {
      const func_name = target.name;

      console.log('before', func_name);

      // let's call some method of this class to actually check if this is the right instance
      // also remember that you have to exclude methods which you are gonna use
      // inside here to avoid “too much recursion” error
      this.main._free.instanceCheck();


      // here we bind method with our class by accessing reference to instance
      const results = target.bind(this.main)(...args);

      console.log('after', func_name, results);
      return results;
    }
  }

  constructor(classAlias) {
    // Get all methods of choosen class
    let methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Foo.prototype );

    // Find and remove constructor as we don't need Proxy on it
    let consIndex = methods.indexOf('constructor');
    if ( consIndex > -1 ) methods.splice(consIndex, 1);

    // Replace all methods with Proxy methods
    methods.forEach( methodName => {
      this[methodName] = new Proxy( this[methodName], this.proxyHandle );
    });
    this.classAlias = classAlias;
  }

  // easies trick to do to avoid infinite loop inside apply is to set your functions
  // inside object, as getOwnPropertyNames from prototype will only get methods
  _free = {
    instanceCheck : () => {
      // this will check if this is our Foo class
      console.log(this.classAlias);
    }
  }

  log() {
    return 'Result';
  }
}

(new Foo('Proxy Class A')).log();

/* 
  Output:
    before log
    Proxy Class A
    after log Result
*/
```

Just wanted to share because I've read in comments that someone had problem to set Proxy. You can read more about Proxies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) more about apply.

Remember that in proxy handle, the `this` is actually `this.main`. For better understanding, you can change it to `classInstance` or something similar.